# Data not listed as dropdown in spinner android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Only the first element of array is listed. Whenever I am clicking on spinner it do not showing other element of spinner.

Code:-

//For spinner

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, medincineName){

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(16);

            return v;

        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,parent);

            ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            //((TextView) v).setPadding(10,10,10,10);

            return v;

        }

    };


    medicineList.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Select Data from spinner
    medicineList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            selectedMedicineName= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Values is: " + selectedMedicineName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            Log.i("Nothing hasbeenSelected","kdnsadkla");
        }
    });
```

Only the first element is showing. When I am trying to click on spinner no dropdown list appears.

Comment: is medincineName is holding data or not?check it out!!

Comment: loop on `medincineName` and make sure that items exist.

Comment: I checked medincineName is holding data. @brahmyadigopula

Comment: Please try add this, adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);, before medicineList.setAdapter(adapter).

Comment: tried @I_A_Mok.. But not helps

Comment: medincineName  only contains 1 element . Show its data or debug if it is generating at run time

Answer (score 0):

create **my_spinner_view.xml** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

and then call this **my_spinner_view.xml** to display spinner view the way you desired.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.my_spinner_view, medincineName){

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(16);

            return v;

        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,parent);

            ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            //((TextView) v).setPadding(10,10,10,10);

            return v;

        }

    };


    medicineList.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Select Data from spinner
    medicineList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            selectedMedicineName= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Values is: " + selectedMedicineName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            Log.i("Nothing hasbeenSelected","kdnsadkla");
        }
    });
```

**or**

you can simple do like this..
create **my_spinner_view2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

and set adapter like bellow snippet

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,
                R.layout.my_spinner_view2, medincineName);
 medicineList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Tried But no luck

Comment: try adding this before setting adapter **adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_view);**

Comment: Not helped @brahmy

Comment: Tried But not helped